# Show that $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across this exercise in a book: Show that $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, where $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is the nullspace or kernel of the matrix $A$ which has $m$ columns.

Comment: Show that if $Ax = 0$ and $Ay = 0$, then $A(x+y) = 0$ and $A(cx) = 0$ for any $c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda I am aware that this is the strategy, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Try adding the equations $Ax = 0$ and $Ay = 0$ to see the first item. For the second, use the fact that $cA = Ac$ for $c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much!

Comment: By the way, OP: the fact that you were aware of the strategy but didn't know how to implement it is great information to include in your original post. That type of context, and display of effort on your part, will help you get better responses in the future.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for this feedback. I'll be sure to keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of a vector space $V$. An efficient way to check if $S$ is a subspace of $V$ is the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test):

> **One-Step Vector Subspace Test.** Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of a vector space $V$. Then $S$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $u+\lambda\cdot v\in S$ for every $u,v\in S$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

In your situation, we are given an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ and $\mathcal{N}(A)\subset \Bbb R^m$ given by 
$$
\mathcal{N}(A)=\{x\in\Bbb R^m: Ax=\mathbf{0}\}
$$
To check if $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$, first note that $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is non-empty, since $\mathbf{0}\in\mathcal{N}(A)$. Then, to use the one-step vector subspace test, let $u,v\in\mathcal{N}(A)$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. We wish to show that $u+\lambda\cdot v\in\mathcal{N}(A)$. Is this true?